# In python, How do I create a abstract base singleton class that can only be initialized once?

Tags: python, oop, singleton, abstract-class

I have this piece of code

```
import abc


class SingletonABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonABCMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Cabc(abc.ABC):
    __metaclass__ = SingletonABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self): pass


class C(Cabc):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"initializing with {a}")
        self._a = a

    def foo(self):
        return self._a


class DoubleC(Cabc):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"initializing with {a}")
        self._a = a

    def foo(self):
        return self._a * 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(C(2).foo())
    print(DoubleC(2).foo())

    print(C(3).foo())
    print(DoubleC(3).foo())
```

it returns

```
initializing with 2
2
initializing with 2
4
initializing with 3
3
initializing with 3
6
```

But I expect it to return

```
initializing with 2
2
initializing with 2
4
2
4
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

Comment: that one I read is not about abc class

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but your class can still be instantiated more than once. So instead of all this rigamarole of defining a metaclass, why don't you just create a factory function that is cached with `@functools.cache`? It would be just as safe and a million times simpler

Comment: please explain here how can it be instantiated more than once https://stackoverflow.com/a/76232000/11065874

Comment: Believe me or not, but your `ABCMeta` implementation is no different from plain metaclass in the linked dupe...

Comment: @AminBa extremely easily. `c = object.__new__(C); c.__init__(3); print(c.foo())`

Comment: A lot of "design patterns" are really just "things we have to use because Java is unweidly, but in other languages, we would use a much easier approach, like just a regular factory function". (I didin't downvote btw, it just saddens me to see this sort of code in the wild)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if a (the input to init) is not mutable, you cannot use cache

Comment: Ok, then you can just manually implement caching, doing pretty much what you are doing in your meta pass `__call__`

Comment: how can I manually do it in a factory function?

Comment: Literally the same exact thing you do in `__call__` in your meta class

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

I changed from using `__metaclass__ = SingletonABCMeta` to the python3 version of it that is `Cabc(abc.ABC, metaclass=SingletonABCMeta)`

```
import abc


class SingletonABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonABCMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Cabc(abc.ABC, metaclass=SingletonABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self): pass


class C(Cabc):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"initializing with {a}")
        self._a = a

    def foo(self):
        return self._a


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(C(2).foo())
    print(C(3).foo())
```

returns:

```
initializing with 2
2
2
```

But now that I think I should raise an exception if I do not want user to create a new instance of this class. Then I am going with this solution

```
import abc


class SingletonABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonABCMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls._instances[cls]
        else:
            raise Exception("This is a singleton. no more than one instance of it can exist")


class Cabc(abc.ABC, metaclass=SingletonABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self): pass


class C(Cabc):

    def __init__(self, a):
        print(f"initializing with {a}")
        self._a = a

    def foo(self):
        return self._a


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(C(2).foo())
    print(C(3).foo())
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed rather than challenging all readers to compare the codes?